# How can I order an SQL result by the number of duplicates?

Tags: mysql

this is my SQL query :

```
SELECT pa.* 
FROM pa 
WHERE pa.id IN ( SELECT prerequis.idpa 
                 FROM prerequis WHERE prerequis.id2a = 18) 
UNION ALL 

SELECT pa.* 
FROM pa 
WHERE pa.id IN ( SELECT prerequis.idpa 
                 FROM prerequis WHERE prerequis.id2a = 15) 
UNION ALL 

SELECT pa.* 
FROM pa 
WHERE pa.id IN ( SELECT prerequis.idpa 
                 FROM prerequis WHERE prerequis.id2a =32);
```

Which gives me a list of elements from the tables pa with duplicates.
Now I want to get a list of the sames pa's ranked according to their redundancy in the first result? (most frequent top).

Thank you all in advance for your help :)

Comment: Um... With a `COUNT(*) AS <columnname>` and then an *ORDER BY <columnname> DESC*. You'll need a GROUP BY, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am pretty new to SQL and I see the big picture here but I don't see how to actually implement this...

Comment: Any halfway decent SQL tutorial will explain how to aggregate data.

Comment: Hi. Explain what happens after you read about and try out ORDER BY. Which you should have already done after reading hits from googling your question. Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

First you dont need UNION ALL here

```
SELECT pa.*, COUNT(*)
FROM pa 
INNER JOIN prerequis pr
  ON pa.id = pr.idpa
WHERE pr.id2a IN (15, 18, 32)
GROUP BY pa.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: thanks! It didn't work with WHERE prerequis.id2a so I changed it to pr.id2a and it seems to work out fine. Thanks again :)

Comment: hi @Juan , you have grouped the data using pa.id and you are using pa.* in your select query. So your query is correct in terms of syntax, but the result in select would be random/vague because of the grouping.

Comment: @user3454116 not really because  `pa.*` is the same for each `id`, what change is `pr.*`

Comment: Momo consider mark this answer as correct if solve your question.